# How hover property work multiple time in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can i change color of font-awesome 2 time with hover property.

```css
.single-post {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:grey;
}

.my-link {
  color: white;
}

.single-post:hover .my-link {
  color: black;
}

.my-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="single-post">
  <i class="my-link fa fa-exchange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Here i am unable to to make it `red` on hover.

How to change color with hover first black and then red??

Comment: change `.my-link:hover` to `.single-post:hover .my-link:hover`

Comment: The short answer is you can't. Not in the way you are thinking. Perhaps with CSS transitions you might be able to achieve something close to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to hover over the link directly and change to red.

```
.single-post:hover .my-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.single-post {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.my-link {
  color: white;
}

.single-post:hover .my-link {
  color: black;
}

.single-post:hover .my-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="single-post">
  <i class="my-link fa fa-exchange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool - might need to approve the answer as well. *thanks!

Comment: How is this handling black then red? I don't get that effect happening.

Comment: the OP wants to hover over the div (and then change the color when hovering the icon) - You can see this from their code that this was their intention. - Honestly, since the OP accepted the answer, it means that the question isn't phrased correctly (i.e. hover twice)

Answer (score 2):

you can use keyframes like this.

```css
.single-post {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: gray;
}
.my-link {
color: white;
}
.single-post:hover .my-link {
  -webkit-animation: coloranimation 0.5s normal forwards; 
  -moz-animation:    coloranimation 0.5s normal forwards;
  -o-animation:      coloranimation 0.5s normal forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes coloranimation {
    0%   {color: white;}
    50%  {color: black;}
    100% {color: red;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes coloranimation {
    0%   {color: white;}
    50%  {color: black;}
    100% {color: red;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="single-post">
  <i class="my-link fa fa-exchange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```